# Short story featuring a teenager on an extraterrestrial base, who inadvertently kills an alien mushroom-like creature?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can anyone identify a short story, which I read in the 1990s but can't find any reference to anywhere?

The story features a teenage protagonist who is based in a scientific exploration base on an alien planet, where she is given the job of searching for possible edible plants. She finds what appears to be a mushroom and chops it down with an axe. Back at the base, the "mushroom" is discovered to have bones!  The story ends with the protagonist being surrounded by tall, mushroom-like creature who "hiss" at her, as if awaiting an explanation...

Thanks in advance! :)